# CruiseControl.NET - Is it possible to trigger tasks on a monthly basis?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to trigger tasks on a monthly basis in a CruiseControl.NET ccnet.config file using a scheduleTrigger block? The target machine is running Windows. I haven't been able to check http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/ as it is currently down.

Answer (score 0):

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331583/cruisecontrol-net-crontrigger-confusion) have mentioned using a cronTrigger, though I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I have come across the cron idea so far. However, I'm running CC.NET on a Windows machine and I'm hoping to avoid having to install cron, if I can (KISS principle). I'll update my question with these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation with cron, which I learned is already supplied with CC.NET and I think it will fit the bill.